Skinned mesh distorts when translating or rotating the body bone
I'm facing a problem in my custom engine with a model exported from blender in glTF format. This model is rendered properly in an engine using Assimp, so I know the model is rigged properly. I want to implement my own movements in my engine without Assimp.
For instance, if I rotate the bone called "body", then the node associated with it and all its children should rotate too.
This is a simple mesh of a snowman consisting of a single mesh with a single skin armature attached to it with 4 nodes and 4 bones in the following hierarchy:

Bone 0: root

Bone 1: body

Bone 2: neck

Bone 3: head







Each node except the root has a unique parent.
If I transform the root node by translating and rotating it, all the vertices are being correctly transformed, so that vertex groups from the body, neck, and head translate and rotate as expected, given that they all are root's children:

However, if I translate and rotate the body node, I get undesirable distortions on the mesh:

I've shared videos at this link with the whole animated motion for both cases. You can also download the glTF file for reproduction with other engines or 3D viewers, so that you can check the problem is not the model.
In the case of body transformation, it seems like some vertices within the node and some from the "neck" and "head" child nodes are not being transformed.
After I loaded all data from the glTF file, I calculate and update each new jointMatrix. In the case of the body bone, I calculate the new local and global transformations as follows, using the gl-matrix library:
//Create new translation and rotation matrix
 
               let T = mat4.create();
                let t = vec3.fromValues(0,0.2*Math.max(Math.sin(gTick*0.1) + 1,0),0);
                mat4.fromTranslation(T,t);
                let R = mat4.create();
                let r = vec3.fromValues(0,0,1);
                mat4.fromRotation(R,0.2*Math.max(Math.sin(gTick*0.05) + 1),r);
//Perform the matrix multiplication and store it in the body node index of the array of local transformations
                let TR = mat4.create();

                localTransformations[2]=mat4.multiply(TR,T,R);

//This local transformation will have to follow parents transformations and all its childs will have to follow it, too. Proceed to create the array for storing all these global transformations.

globalTransformations = [];
//Global transformation of node 0 (head node)          

let m=mat4.create();                
mat4.multiply(m,localTransformations[3],localTransformations[2]);
                let m2=mat4.create();
                mat4.multiply(m2,m,localTransformations[1]);
                let m3=mat4.create();
                mat4.multiply(m3,m2,localTransformations[0]);
                globalTransformations.push(m3);
                
//Global transformation of node 1 (neck node) 
                m=mat4.create();
                mat4.multiply(m,localTransformations[3],localTransformations[2]);
                m2=mat4.create();
                mat4.multiply(m2,m,localTransformations[1]);
                globalTransformations.push(m2);
//Global transformation of node 2 (body node) 
                m=mat4.create();
                mat4.multiply(m,localTransformations[3],localTransformations[2]);
                globalTransformations.push(m);

//Global transformation of node 3 (root node)=local transformation, given it has no parents.      
       globalTransformations.push(localTransformations[3]);

//Find the new joints matrix, and store it on an JSON object. Information of the node associated with the bone is retrieved from globalTransformation array.        
                let jointM;
                for(let i=0; i < jointsInfo.length;i++){
                    jointM = mat4.create();
                    console.log(jointsInfo[i]);
                    mat4.multiply(jointM,globalTransformations[jointsInfo[i].node],invBindMatrices[i]);
                    jointsInfo[i].matrix=jointM;
                }
//Fill the jointsMatrix array with the jointsMatrix stored on jointsInfo object.
                let jInd=0;
                for(let i=0; i < jointsInfo.length;i++){

                  jointM=jointsInfo[i].matrix;
                    for(let j=0; j < jointM.length; j++) {
                        jointsMatrix[jInd]=jointM[j];
                        jInd++;
                    }
                }

Code for the vertex shader:
#version 300 es
    layout (location = 0) in vec3 aVertexPosition;
    layout (location = 1) in vec3 aVertexNormal;
    layout (location = 2) in vec2 aVertexTextCoord;
    layout (location = 3) in ivec4 aJointIndices;
    layout (location = 4) in vec4 aJointWeights;
    uniform mat4 uViewMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uModelMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uProjectionMatrix;
    uniform mat4 jointsMatrix[4];
    out vec3 outPos;
    out vec3 outNormals;
    flat out ivec4 outJointIndices;
    out vec4 outWeight;
    
    void main() {
      vec4 initPos = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0);

        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            float weight = aJointWeights[i];
            if(weight > 0.0) {
                count++;
                int jointIndex = aJointIndices[i];
                vec4 tmpPos = jointsMatrix[jointIndex] * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
                initPos += weight * tmpPos;
            }
        }
        if (count == 0)
        {
            initPos = vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
        }  
      gl_Position = uProjectionMatrix * uViewMatrix * uModelMatrix * initPos;
      outPos = aVertexPosition;
      outNormals = aVertexNormal;
      outJointIndices = aJointIndices;
      outWeight = aJointWeights;
    }

The transformation from the root node demonstrates maybe this is not a problem from global transformations, as every child from the root are correctly transformed. What could be wrong?
Edit: I found how to reproduce the bug. Even if I translate or rotate the root node, this can also happen if I don't use global transformations at all. So if every child of root node are not being transformed, why some vertex within body, neck, or head are indeed translated and rotated? I then made the color of the fragments to ouput the values of the bone indexes:

which is generated using the following line on fragment shader:
fragColor = vec4(vec3(col/3.,1.,1.),1);

where "col" is the X component of the jointIndex vec4, given that every other component is zero. I divide by 3 because that is the maximum index on the jointIndex array. The bone indexed as 3 refers to head node, bone index 2 refers to neck node, bone index 1 refers to body node and bone index 0 refers to root node. So, if the ouput is vec3(1,1,1), meaning that it's bone index 3 (head node), we see a fragment with white color. As we move to the bone index 0 (root node), we see a fragment of light blue. Judging by the image, it obviously seems that some of the vertex in the head node have a blue color, which is indicative of that has assined the root bone index.
Hence, I think this has probably something to do with the data. In this link I have uploaded the gltf file and the binary file in case someone can retrieve the bone indexes and try to make this work.
